# Batch: Show last user input

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

(This is my first post here, so bear with me)

Can you show the last user-input in a batch file? I'm gonna try to keep it simple here.

```
@echo off

:menu
echo Type 1 to proceed.
set /p example=
if "%example%" == "1" GOTO :proceed
GOTO :error

:proceed
pause

:error
cls
echo You wrote (last user input), that's not correct.
timeout 30
GOTO :menu
```

I know that I could replace the (last user input) with %example%, but then I'd have to make custom error messages for every category, and there are about 50 of them. It'd be easier with a last input command.

By the way, I've taught myself everything that I know about batch, so my example probably has major issues right now, but it works somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could centralize all user input into a function (user_input)

```
:menu1
echo Type 1 to proceed.
call :userInput example
if "%example%" == "1" GOTO :proceed
GOTO :error

:menu2
echo Type 42 to proceed.
call :userInput answer
if "%answer%" == "42" GOTO :proceed
GOTO :error

:userInput
set /p LAST_INPUT=
set "%1=%LAST_INPUT%"
exit /b

:proceed
pause

:error
cls
echo You wrote "%LAST_INPUT%", that's not correct.
timeout 30
GOTO :menu
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do it without temp file. TO get the things written int the console you need the `doskey /history` (this will skip the running of the script itself):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "last="
set "but_last="
doskey /history > log.txt
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in (log.txt) do (
    set "but_last=!last!"
    set "last=%%#"
)

echo "%but_last%"
del /s /q log.txt >nul 2>nul
```

Comment: Good solution, but perhaps a little bit of overkill :-)